# NetBeans changing order of keys in HashMap

Tags: java, netbeans, hashmap, key-value

It appears that NetBeans tends to modify the order of *key-value* pairs when placing them into a `HashMap` as compared to the `HashMap` objects created by calling `javac.exe` and `java.exe` directly.

Consider the following class definitions (`package` and `import` declarations omitted):

```
class Coder {

    enum Gender { FEMALE, MALE  }
    String name;
    Gender gender;

    Coder(String name, Gender gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    String getName() { return name; }
    Gender getGender() { return gender; }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Coder> list = Arrays.asList(
                new Coder("Alice", Coder.Gender.FEMALE),
                new Coder("Chuck", Coder.Gender.MALE),
                new Coder("Bob", Coder.Gender.MALE));
        Map<Coder.Gender, List<String>> classification = list.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Coder::getGender,
                                 Collectors.mapping(Coder::getName, Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println(classification);

        // Getting metainfo:
        System.out.println("Actual map's type at runtime is " +
                           classification.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("OS: " + System.getProperty("os.name") +
                           ", ver." + System.getProperty("os.version"));
        System.out.println("Java ver.: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));

        // Serializing:
        String filename = "classification_cmd.ser";
        // String filename = "classification_NetBeans.ser";  // toggle commenting-out as needed
        File file = new File(filename);
        try (
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream outs = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)
        )
        { outs.writeObject(classification);
        } catch (IOException ioe) { ioe.printStackTrace(); };
    }
}
```

Compiling and running the above code directly from command line in Windows (Java ver.1.8.0_066) produced this:

```
{MALE=[Chuck, Bob], {FEMALE=[Alice]}
```

Under Linux from the CLI on my Raspberry Pi (Java ver.1.80_065) and via [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/) (Java ver.1.8.0_112) results were essentially the same: first MALE group, then FEMALE one. However, in NetBeans 8.1 under Windows (Java ver.1.8.0_066) the output was reversed:

```
{FEMALE=[Alice], MALE=[Chuck, Bob]}
```

In all cases the actual type of the map in question was `HashMap`. Serializing the map to disk and peeking inside confirmed that the objects were indeed different in terms of the order of *key-value* pairs:

**- from command line:**
[image]

**- from inside NetBeans:**
[image]

Hence my questions:

- Why does it happen, and
- What should be done (I mean, apart from forced sorting such as employing a `TreeMap` built around a custom `Comparator`, etc.) to ensure that results will be exactly the same regardless of how we compile and run our programs, from command line or from within NetBeans?

Comment: I understand you'll still want to know why it happens, but this is important: "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time." - [HashMap Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: Yes, I do realize all that and didn't address this subject out of idle curiosity. Imagine my surprise when I was writing my OCP exam (1Z0-809) where one of the quizzes was constructed similarly to my question and therefore contained two equally probable, mutually reversed options although I was supposed to tick off only one. What makes the question even more baffling, "there are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map or List objects returned" (as per javadoc on Collectors.groupingBy()). I was just hoping there's something more to it...

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that a general Map implementation retains any order of the added elements.

If you do care about that order, you do need to use a NavigableMap like TreeMap which keeps the keys ordered. You don't usually need to provide a Comparator, it uses they key type's natural order if none is given.